# back function in STL

Tags: c++, stl, back

I read everywhere that back() function return reference to the last element, but I have a doubt.

I created a vector with elements 1,3,5 resp.Then I wrote the following code

```
int i = v.back();
i++;
```

after the above two statements , I printed the vector and I got the output 1 3 5
whereas it should be 1 3 6 as I incremented the reference.

but when i do (v.back())++ and then print the values of the vector I get the result

```
1 3 6
```

I don't understand the difference in output , according to me it should be same.
Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 8):

The code does not increment the last element via a reference, it increments a *copy* of the last element. Change to:

```
int& i = v.back();
i++;
```

Comment: okay maybe i am wrong but as said back() function returns a reference therefore i is a reference to the last element.so what's the need of &i. thanks

Comment: Yep, `back()` does return a reference but that does not make `i` a reference implicitly. You have to declare `i` as a reference otherwise it copies the object to which the return value of `back()` refers.

Comment: @user1139048: back() returns a reference, but by `int i=v.back();` you just use the value behind this reference to initialise a local variable (which is independent from your vector). `int& i=v.back();` stores the reference itself, so you can change the vector element via i.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = v.back();
i++;
```

This will increment `i`, not the value inside the vector. If you want to increment the last element of the vector, either do as you did (with `(v.back())++`) or use a reference:

```
int& i = v.back();
i++;
// v.back is now +1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/back/%20vector%3a%3aback%28%29), back() returns reference. To alter your item assign it to reference or pointer, like so:

```
int& iref = v.back();
int* iptr = &v.back();
```

All further modification of these variables will cause changes in vector element.